# Договор или Договор

Tags: орфография

Не могу найти четкую информацию о том, как в служебных записках, письмах писать слово "договор": с большой или маленькой буквы?
Употребляется в следующей форме "договор № 0003/14 от 20.01.2014 ".
Например: В соответствии с договором № 5 от 23.11.09 просим Вас....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь пишется прописная буква, так как Договор - это первое слово официального названия документа.

И далее в тексте этот документ может называться одним словом - Договор, например: Настоящий Договор вступает в силу с момента подписания.. (Проверено по реальному "Договору №____ на управление многоквартирным домом").

Comment: это просто служебка, договор там упоминается, он не фигурирует в документе постоянно, просто на него ссылаются. При этом дан номер, то есть это не алиас. Договор № такой-то.... мне казалось, что конкретизация с помощью номера позволяет писать слово "договор" с маленькой буквы. 
С большой пишется, если ранее было "Далее - Договор", то есть подразумевается упомянутый выше документ, а не любой договор в принципе. А здесь дается номер - и так понятно, что за договор. Зачем его еще и большой буквой награждать....

Comment: В таком случае можно, наверное, не награждать, пусть это будет нарицательное существительное, а № - его несогласованное определение. Правилам орфографии такая форма не противоречит, в то же время существуют какие-то традиции в оформлении служебной документации, которые приходится учитывать.